# split a mysql string from group_concat into array to use IN() function

Tags: string, split, group-concat

Split a string from group_concat function into array to use IN function in mysql. but don't use find_in_set. let me know another way.

Answer (score 0):

Although find_in_set is best function,But if you want to try other techniques,then try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE 
CONCAT(',', field_name, ',') LIKE '%,".(int)$value_to_find.",%'");
```